# Comma placement after a date

Tags: commas, writing-style

The following sentence is from The Economist:

***On March 14th*** concerns about China’s grip on Congo’s cobalt production deepened when GEM, a Chinese battery maker, said it would acquire a third of the cobalt shipped by Glencord, the world’s biggest producer of the metal, between 2018 and 2020.

At first, I thought The Economist made a typo: a comma should have been placed after the date "March 14th," which builds a better flow for the sentence in my opinion.

However, I encountered today this sentence from another article by The Economist that is also missing a comma after a date:

***On May 23rd*** the Department of Commerce launched a probe of car imports.

Judging from the fact a comma is persistently omitted in articles by The Economist, I am starting to wonder if the comma usage hinges on stylistic choice rather than is a universal rule in English grammar. Personally, I am used to seeing a date set off by a comma and does not prefer The Economist way.

Let me know what you guys think. Thank you in advance.